# Async BCL and .net 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0, wix, installation, async-await

I have a WPF application that targets framework v4.0 and uses async BCL. It seems that installing only .net framework v4.0 on fresh W7 OS is not enough, since as it seems, there was a bug which was corrected with later update. For example, installing update v4.0.3 solves the problem with using async BCL on framework v4.0.

My concern is this: On my developer machine (W8.1) I do not have this update installed (at least it is not registered in windows registry, nor under the windows updates). Still, my application is working just fine, which means that the update is somehow installed through some other method.

The question: how can I know that application that uses async BCL will work correctly on client's OS? Currently, when I install the application (wix 3.8), I check if .net 4.0 is installed, and I check if KB2600211 (4.0.3) is installed (by searching adequate registry keys). If not, I install them, but I am wondering if searching for KB2600211 is the right approach? Is there some other way to make sure that app will work correctly?

Comment: Can't you say "search for kb on W7" "search .net 4.0 on W8"?

Answer (score 2):

On your Windows 8.1 you have .NET 4.5.1 which is an in-place update for .NET 4.5 which is an in-place update for .NET 4.0. That means you no longer have plain .NET 4.0 (.NET 4.0.x, for that matter).

I recommend you to always test on the target environments. It can be as simple as having a VM.